# cordova executescript with setinterval is causing keyboard to appear and disappear in inappbrowser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I created a custom header for the opened website using insertcss and executescript

Since I have to call functions from cordova plugins and they won't work in the executescript's file, i called them in the execute script's callback function.
I put setinterval to constantly check for the values[0]. Depending on the value, it will do a different function..

My code works fine in Galaxy Note 10.1 and iOS but when we tried it in Samsung Duos and Samsung Mega, the keyboard would keep blinkig(I noticed these phones have a different looking keyboard). When I tried to removed the executescript code, the keyboard just stays when i focus on an input field as it should.

This is my code:

```
 ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event)
                {


                    ref.insertCSS({  file: "http://viveg.net/inappbrowserfiles/custom.css" },function(){ /*alert('css inserted');*/});

                    ref.executeScript({ file: "http://viveg.net/inappbrowserfiles/custom.js"}, 

                                      function(values){

                                                    clearInterval(bTimerId);

                                                    bTimerId = setInterval(
                                                   function(values)
                                                    {
                                                         scancounter = 0;
                                                         locationcounter = 0;
                                                         closecounter = 0;
                                                        focusedcounter  = 0;
                                                         focusedoutcounter =  0;

                                                        ref.executeScript(
                                                        { code:'getSomething()' },
                                                            function(values){
                                                            var data = values[0];
                                                                //alert(data.func);
                                                                if(data.func == 'close')
                                                                {
                                                                   if(closecounter == 0)
                                                                   {
                                                                       closecounter += 1;
                                                                       ref.close();
                                                                       askExit();
                                                                       clearInterval(bTimerId);
                                                                   }
                                                                }
                                                                else if(data.func == 'scan')
                                                                {
                                                                   if(scancounter == 0)
                                                                   {
                                                                       scancounter += 1;
                                                                       ref.close();
                                                                       $('.content-cont').html('<img src="img/loading.gif" style="margin:15% auto; width:25%; display:block;"/>'); 
                                                                       clearInterval(bTimerId);

                                                                         setTimeout(function()
                                                                        {
                                                                         scanner.startScanning(MWBSInitSpace.init,MWBSInitSpace.callback);
                                                                        }, 2250);

                                                                   }
                                                                }
                                                                else if(data.func == 'location')
                                                                {
                                                                   if(locationcounter == 0)
                                                                   {
                                                                       locationcounter += 1;
                                                                       ref.close();
                                                                       $('.content-cont').empty();
                                                                       clearInterval(bTimerId);
                                                                       chooseurl();
                                                                   }
                                                                }
                                                                else if(data.func == 'focused')
                                                                {
                                                                   if(focusedcounter == 0)
                                                                   {
                                                                    focusedcounter += 1;
                                                                    //clearInterval(bTimerId);
                                                                    cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show();

                                                                   }
                                                                }
                                                                else if(data.func == 'focusedout')
                                                                {
                                                                   if(focusedoutcounter == 0)
                                                                   {
                                                                    focusedoutcounter += 1;

                                                                   }
                                                                }



                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                   , 2000);                                                   

                    });


                });
```

Does anyone know how to make the keyboard stay? Or know another way to communicate between inappbrowser and the app that doesn't have bugs likes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out now. in my custom.js file, I changed the

```
 <button></button>
```

to

```
 <a href=""></a>
```

and used a url with parameters like

http://example.com/?valll=close or http://example.com/?valll=scan

in cordova side. in loadstart's callback, i just called a function to get the value of 'valll'. and depending on valll's value(either 'close' or 'scan'), it will do ref.close();
or call the barcode scanner function :p